# Is Android's construction with listeners available in Windows Phone?

Tags: java, c#, android, windows-phone-8

In Android I can use listeners like this:

Class1.java:

```
public class Class1 {

    public Class1() {
        Class2 c = new Class2();
        c.setOnFinishListener(new Class2.OnFinishListener() {
            @Override
            void onFinish(String result) {
                // My result's handling here
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Class2.java:

```
public class Class2 {

    private OnFinishListener mOnFinishListener;

    public void setOnFinishListener(OnFinishListener onFinishListener) {
        mOnFinishListener = onFinishListener;
    }

    private void someMethod() {
        String result="Result here";
        if (mOnFinishListener != null) mOnFinishListener.onFinish(result);
    }

    public interface OnFinishListener {
        void onFinish(String result);
    }

}
```

Is something like this available in C#? How to implement communication between classes like this using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way in C# is to use events:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        var c = new Class2();

        c.OnFinish += result => 
        {
            // My result handling here
        };
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public event Action<string> OnFinish;

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        string result = "Result here";

        var eventHandler = this.OnFinish;

        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(result);
        }       
    }
}
```